# When I solve an equation using `Reduce`, the possible results look very mixed in some cases

Tags: equation-solving

When I solve an equation using `Reduce`, the possible results look very mixed in some cases.

For example;

```
Reduce[16*a^4*\[Lambda]*\[Mu]*E^((4*Gamma[3*\[Delta] + 2*\[Sigma] + 1]*(x^\[Alpha] - t^\[Alpha]))/\[Alpha]) + 8*a^2*\[Chi]*(12*\[Gamma]*\[Nu] + (\[Lambda] - 12)*\[Mu])*
 E^((2*Gamma[3*\[Delta] + 2*\[Sigma] + 1]*(x^\[Alpha] - t^\[Alpha]))/\[Alpha]) + \[Lambda]*\[Mu]*\[Chi]^2 == 0]
```

[image]

How to get a more understandable view?

**P.S.** Printing all possibilities one under the other might be an option. But `%//Column` or `%//TableForm` doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
red = Reduce[
16*a^4*\[Lambda]*\[Mu]*
 E^((4*Gamma[
       3*\[Delta] + 2*\[Sigma] + 1]*(x^\[Alpha] - 
        t^\[Alpha]))/\[Alpha]) + 
8*a^2*\[Chi]*(12*\[Gamma]*\[Nu] + (\[Lambda] - 12)*\[Mu])*
 E^((2*Gamma[
       3*\[Delta] + 2*\[Sigma] + 1]*(x^\[Alpha] - 
        t^\[Alpha]))/\[Alpha]) + \[Lambda]*\[Mu]*\[Chi]^2 == 0];

TraditionalForm[
red //. Or -> 
Composition[(Column[#, Right, Background -> {{White, LightGray}}, 
   Frame -> All] &), List]]
```